# How to get numbers arranged right to left in sql server SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When performing SELECT statements including number columns (prices, for example), the result always is left to right ordered, which reduces the readability. Therefore I'm searching a method to format the output of number columns right to left.

I already tried to use something like

```
SELECT ... SPACE(15-LEN(A.Nummer))+A.Nummer ...
   FROM Artikel AS A ...
```

which gives close results, but depending on font not really. An alternative would be to replace 'SPACE()' with 'REPLICATE('_',...)', but I don't really like the underscores in output.

Beside that this formula will crash on numbers with more digits than 15, therefore I searched for a way finding the maximum length of entries to make it more save like

```
SELECT ... SPACE(MAX(A.Nummer)-LEN(A.Nummer))+A.Nummer ...
   FROM Artikel AS A ...
```

but this does not work due to the aggregate character of the MAX-function.

So, what's the best way to achieve the *right-justified* order for the number-columns?

Thanks,
Rainer

Comment: How are you displaying your query results now in that they "always end up in left to right ordered"?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use right-justified text in your user interface.

Comment: Ok, 'right justified text' would be more appropriate to describe the result I'm longing for - but only in the columns with numbers...

Comment: That very quickly becomes a client-side issue. E.g. your application should know which columns represent numbers, and then it can do things like `<td align="right">`...

Comment: Thanks Aaron, in my case i want to use it as RowSource for a listbox in Access, which does not allow something like that - or it will make it much more complicated (according to my state of knowledge...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you problem with the list box solved have a look at this link: http://www.lebans.com/List_Combo.htm
I strongly believe that this type of adjustment should be made in the UI layer and not mixed in with data retrieval.

But to answer your original question i have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aa8e/4):

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.some_numbers(n INT);
```

Create some example data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.some_numbers
SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID())
  FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))X(x);
```

The following query is using the `OVER()` clause to specify that the `MAX()` is to be applied over all rows. The `>` and `<` that the result is wrapped in is just for illustration purposes and not required for the solution.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT '>'+
       SPACE(MAX(LEN(CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX))))OVER()-LEN(CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX))))+
       CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX))+
       '<'
  FROM dbo.some_numbers SN;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aa8e/4/0)**:

```
|      COLUMN_0 |
|---------------|
| >-1486993739< |
| > 1620287540< |
| >-1451542215< |
| >-1257364471< |
| > -819471559< |
| >-1364318127< |
| >-1190313739< |
| > 1682890896< |
| >-1050938840< |
| >  484064148< |
```

This query does a straight case to show the difference:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT '>'+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'<'
  FROM dbo.some_numbers SN;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9aa8e/4/1)**:

```
|      COLUMN_0 |
|---------------|
| >-1486993739< |
|  >1620287540< |
| >-1451542215< |
| >-1257364471< |
|  >-819471559< |
| >-1364318127< |
| >-1190313739< |
|  >1682890896< |
| >-1050938840< |
|   >484064148< |
```

With this query you still need to change the display font to a monospaced font like `COURIER NEW`. Otherwise, as you have noticed, the result is still misaligned.

Comment: WOW, Sebastian, that's impressive... ;) The 'OVER()' makes the difference - event though currently I don't understand fully what it does in this circumstance.
Anyhow, now I can incur a 'almost right justified' number column within a set of (left-justified-)text columns, as long as I don't use monospaced character sets.

Comment: Hadn't expected such an answer anymore, so I was take by surprise when I returned to this website today... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind marking this as excepted answer? :)